# Can't modify properties of ToolStripMenuItems in their onClick events

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

On my onClick event handler, i'm doing something like:

```
private void myToolStripItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form form = (Form)(((taskBarToolStripMenuItem)sender).formReference);

        if (form != this.ActiveMdiChild)
        {
            if (!form.Visible)
                form.Show();
            form.Activate();

            ((taskBarToolStripMenuItem)sender).isSelected = true; //set it to true, so the renderer will draw them differently
        }
    }
```

taskBarToolStripMenuItem is a subclass of ToolStripMenuItem. When i get to my custom ToolStripSystemRenderer, items that i'm sure got its "isSelected" property changed to true remain with it as false. This happens to other properties, i tried Tag, Text, etc... Why? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is to cast the `sender` to an instance of the `ToolStripMenuItem`.
Try casting to the type instead like so.

```
((ToolStripMenuItem)sender).Selected = true;
```

If you're going to use it in a number of places, you can set it to a temporary variable to avoid unboxing every time.

```
private void myToolStripItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var item = (ToolStripMenuItem)sender; // temp variable
    Form form = (Form)(item.formReference);

    if (form != this.ActiveMdiChild)
    {
        if (!form.Visible)
            form.Show();
        form.Activate();

        item.Selected = true; //set it to true, so the renderer will draw them differently
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that: var item = (ToolStripMenuItem)sender; item.Tag = "MYTAG"; . Then, on "OnRenderMenuItemBackground" of the renderer, i do Console.WriteLine((ToolStripMenuItem)e.Item.Tag); and i get null. Could anything be rewriting the MenuItems properties? I'm pretty sure the "var item =" and "e.Item" are the same reference.

Comment: Are you sure your not mixing this renderer with a renderer on another item? I had to try this in code and it worked out fine.

Comment: @helgeheldre I'm sure. Actually, inside myToolStripItem_Click(), if i do something to the item, like item.Text = "Change", the text of the item won't change either. It seems that for some reason, the sender object is not being passed by reference in my case, so i can't modify the source object.

Comment: Are you using a toolStrip or a contextMenu? And do you need to make your actions in the renderer? I think there is a difference in how the framework handles rendering of ContextMenuStrip and ToolStrip even tought CMS inherits rendering from ToolStrip